# How to spawn multiple sprites? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i create multiple sprites from a sprite object?
image load:

```
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/monster.png";
```

Here is my sprite object.

```
function monster(speed,hp,dmg,sight,x,y)
{
    this.speed= speed; 
    this.hp= hp; 
    this.dmg= dmg; 
    this.sight = sight; 
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y; 
}
```

the variable that creates a new monster:

```
var monster = new monster(50, 50+(hero.level * 5), 10 + (hero.level * 5), false, 500, (32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64))));
```

And my render:

```
ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
```

I can't figure out how to create multiple instances of the monster without creating multiple variables.

Cheers Phil

Comment: An array seems a good starting point.

Comment: Okay, i have made an array, each instance containing the var monster. Problem is, they are all spawning at the same location, i want the y axis to be random on each one.

Comment: Don't call the variable name the same as the function name... got it working now

Comment: @Phil You might want to post your solution as an answer to the question, so other users can benefit more fully from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to be having a function called monster and a variable called monster, solution was to change variable name to baddy so

```
var baddy = new monster(50, 50+(hero.level * 5), 10 + (hero.level * 5), false, 500, (32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64))));
```

Cheers